check if mediatracks from audiocontext api is empty
I'm currently building a audio to video instance. While there is no problem to capture the canvas.captureStream(25).getVideoTracks(), the audioctx.added.stream.getAudioTracks() is.
let audioctx=new(window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext)()),stream;
audioctx.added=audioctx.createMediaStreamDestination()

then steam=new MediaStream([...canvas.captureStream(25).getVideoTracks(),...audioctx.added.stream.getAudioTracks()]) the mediarecorder records both streams as then codec reveals, but there is no audio within the video.
different ways to add mediatracks to stream, but always the same result.
while writing this i forgot to add audioctx.createMediaElementSource(_audio_element_).

my last comment didn't helped. thanks for any help. i just so a typo, steam is steam

e6.stream=chrome()?e6.captureStream():e6.mozCaptureStream();

e6=audioNode
chrome() returns if it is a chrome browser or not.

